# How to allocate memory for double pointer and it should be visible in f1, f2 and f3?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

My sample program is below.

```
void function1 () {
    void **data
    function2(data);
    //Will access data here
}

void function2(void **data) {
    function3(data);
    //Will access data here
}

void function3(void **data) {
    //Need to allocate memory here says 100 bytes for data
    //Populate some values in data
}
```

My actual need:

1. void* should be allocated in function1
2. that should be passed across function2 and function3
3. memory must be allocated in function3 only.
4. data must be accessed in function2 and function3

Could you please help me how to do this?

Thanks,
Boobesh

Comment: How do you think you should do it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. I suspect you need `void *data = ...` in `function1()`, and you pass it with `function2(&data);`.  You need to have a good understanding of what you're allocating.  Using `void *` (let alone `void **`) can hide a multitude of mistakes and the compiler can't help you because almost anything can be passed.  So, avoid a `void *` whenever you can.  Function 3 is unwriteable on the specification we have.

Comment: Jonathan, I can initialize data in function1 with only NULL not with any memory allocation. May be my sample program is not correct. But with my steps(My actual need) can you please give any sample program to achieve this?

Comment: Kunal, Do you think we can do this only through global varialble. I mean if void* is only a global varialbe?

Comment: Pass the required info as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

OP expresses conflicting needs for `data`

In `function1()`, `data` is a "**pointer** to pointer to void".
Yet in `function3()` OP wants `data` to be  "... 100 bytes for **data**".

A more typical paradigm is that `data` in `function1()` is

```
void function1 () {
  void *data = NULL;
  function2(&data);  // Address of data passed, so funciton2() receives a void **
  //Will access data here
  unsigned char *ucp = (unsigned char *) data;
  if ((ucp != NULL) && (ucp[0] == 123)) { 
    ;  // success
  }
  ...
  // Then when done
  free(data);
  data = 0;
}
```

Then in this case the memory allocation for `data` in `function3()` is

```
void function3(void **data) {
  if (data == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  // Need to allocate memory here.  Say 100 bytes for data
  size_t Length = 100;
  *data = malloc(Length);
  if (data != NULL) {
    //Populate some values in data
    memset(*data, 123, Length);
  }
}

void function2(void **data) {
  if (data == NULL) {
    return;
  }
  function3(data);
  unsigned char *ucp = (unsigned char *) *data;
  // Will access data here
  if ((ucp != NULL) &&  (ucp[0] == 123)) { 
    ;  // success
  }
}
```